# How does luasocket's settimeout() work?

Tags: networking, tcp, lua, love2d

I have the following code:

```
function Server:run()
    print("Running.")
    self.running = true
    while self.running do
        if self.client == nil then
            self.client = self.socket:accept()
            print("Client connected.")
            self.client:settimeout(10)
        end
        local line, err = self.client:receive()
        if err then
            print("Error: " .. err)
        elseif line == "quit" then
            print("Quitting.")
            self.client:close()
            self.running = false        
        else
            print("Received: " .. line)
        end
    end
    self:terminate()
end
```

I expect that when self.client:receive() is called, the server will wait for 10 seconds or until it has a message, and then continue on its way.

However, this is not the behaviour I experience. The server instead instantly generates a timeout error no matter what value the timeout is set to, and doesn't wait at all for a message from the client.

I suspect I've misunderstood something. Any insight would be appreicated. Thanks.

---

Full code here:

Server: http://pastie.org/9659701

main: http://pastie.org/9659703

---

Answer (score 1):

The code works for me as expected (Windows, LuaJIT 2.0.2, luasocket 3.0-rc1); I tested on the following standalone script:

```
local socket = require "socket"
local server = assert(socket.bind("*", 3333))
local client = server:accept()
print("accepted connection; waiting for data...")
client:settimeout(10)
local start = os.time()
local line, err, partial = client:receive("*l")
if line then
  print(("received '%s'; echoing back..."):format(line))
  client:send(line.."\n")
else
  print(("received error '%s' after %.2f seconds."):format(err, os.time()-start))
end
client:close()
```

You can run `telnet localhost 3333` and should see "accepted connection; waiting for data..."; if I don't send anything, I get "received error 'timeout' after 10.00 seconds.", which is exactly what I'd expect.

I'd check if there is a logic error and `self.client` is never `nil` in your case and you don't call `settimeout`. If this still doesn't help, make a standalone example that we can run using love2d (for example, I don't see where you call `bind`).